# Android Java: Parsing values in cyrillic from XML with no UTF-8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, utf-8, xml-parsing

The XML file starts with

```
<rss version="2.0"
 xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
 xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
 xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
 xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/">

<channel>
    <title>
```

I noticed that UTF-8 is missing, if I am not mistaking

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

When I try to parse the values with cyrillic characters from the XML file I get something like

```
<description><![CDATA[���� ���������������� ���� ��������������, ������ �������������� ���������� ���������� ���� ������������������, �������������� �� ���������������� ������������ ���������������� ���� ���������������������� �������������� �� ����������������.

     �������� ������ ����������������...]]>
```

Thank you for your help. BTW I parse the XML with Jsoup using Parse.xmlParser method (class/parser).

Comment: You have to use the encoding that the document was created with. Perhaps you are receiving that information via HTTP response header Content-Type. For successful communication, you have to be able to follow what the sender is doing.

Comment: here is the link of the xml source code view-source:https://nezavisen.mk/mk/rss.xml

Comment: can i somehow encode cyrillic after i convert the xml code to a string, because encoding in the xml file is missing

Comment: "after i convert the xml code to a string": No, you can't convert bytes to a string without knowing the encoding. That's fundamental to all text communication. However, in certain contexts, especially for well-defined languages, the specification states how you can detect the encoding. For XML, that includes trying to read the XML processing instruction (if present) to see if declares the encoding. The specification has other provisions, too. But why are you doing this? There must be a hundred libraries available. Please show your code.

Comment: **XML** [Autodetection of Character Encodings](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-guessing)

Comment: I was using Ion to extract the content of the xml file and then send as a string value to Jsoup (Jsoup.parse method as I mentioned before). So, I ve fixed the issue open xml link with Jsoup.connect method. I found out that using Ion to extract content and then using jsoup.parse methd is a bit faster then to extract the content directly with Jsoup. Isn't that weird? Thank you guys.